# Getting the previous date and time

Tags: php, date

I'm currently working on a website where customers are able to cancel an order, but they can only cancel it up to 4pm 1 day before the end of the order.
I know how to get the previous day, but I can't figure out how to find out if it's 4pm or not.

```
$prevDay = date("Y-m-d h:m:s", strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($order->date."00:00:00")));
```

This gives me this output: 2011-05-08 12:05:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$prevDay = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-1 day')) . " 16:00:00";
$orderTime = $order->date."00:00:00";
if($orderTime < $prevDay) {
    // do stuff
}
```

EDIT: Wait, not sure if the logic is right there, but in principle the $prevDay value should give you the date of 4PM yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ordertime = strtotime($order->date);
$prevday = strtotime('-1 day' , $ordertime);
if (time() < $prevday && date('H') < 16) {
// it's okay to cancel
}
```

Answer (score 0):

anything more then 12 is after noon forexample 13 14 15 till the 24. then explode the output with space character and

```
$time = db_value

$time = explode('',$time);

compare $time[1] > 16
```

i hope the above sudu code helps you